# How to perform click event at a specific date and time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am generating a mail manager project in Asp.Net. I want that the mail should be sent when it is scheduled. One can create mail contents and then select date and time to send mail. The mail should be sent at that time only. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's not the responsibility of the UI at all.  You're better off having the information gathered by the user stored somewhere (database, message bus, whatever) and then having another process, outside your asp.net app, manage the mail queue by querying it for any mail that needs to be sent every X refresh (e.g. every 15 minutes; every 10 minutes; every hour; every day; whatever fidelity you need based on the resources available and number of jobs expected).